# Debug Python starting on specific line, not at beginning, like VBA

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

I am using the Spyder IDE, version 3.3.1, and I would like to debug only a specific line of Python code that's about 1,100 lines into the program. I don't want to run all the code above line 1,100. Running those 1,100 lines would take time since it would execute various large database queries, and be unnecessary for my purposes.

In Visual Basic (VBA) for Excel, when debugging, I can drag the yellow arrow to any line and run the code line-by-line from that point forward. Is there something similar in Python (specifically in the Spyder IDE), or do I have to set break points and run the entire code?

I suppose one option is to move this specific line of code to the top of the file (i.e. line 1, not line 1,100), so that it runs first when debugging. Maybe I've answered my own question, but I'm still curious whether there's a way to start debugging from a certain line.

My options seem limited to the following, judging by Spyder's debug menu:

1. Run current line (i.e. starting at line 1)
2. Step into function or method of current line
3. Run until current function or method returns
4. Continue execution until next breakpoint

I don't want to reorganize all my code, since this is just an ad hoc/one-time analysis. For context, I am a business analyst and I am just doing some data exploration/correlation/regression analysis. I am a functional programmer whose background is in business/finance, not computer science.

Comment: Probably not the correct way: block-comment out all the functions that return values to names in the global namespace and rerun. Everything in the global namespace will still be accessible each time you run your script

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) From your description is not clear if the line of code you want to debug requires some results from the previous code. Is that the case or not?

Comment: Good question. Yes, it requires objects (dataframes, etc) created in the previous code, but they're saved in the global namespace, so that does not cause problems for me. To solve my problem, I followed my own suggestion and copied the line I wanted to debug to the top of the code (i.e. line 1), and started the debug from there. Pretty easy to do as a workaround.

Comment: Sorry for not coming back to you. For next time, you can insert this line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the point you want to start debugging (this is a programmatic way to create breakpoints), then split your file in cells (with a comment of the form `#%%` before that line), then execute the first cell (i.e. the code with your first 1100 lines) with `Shift+Enter`, and finally your second cell, the one that contains the `pdb` code I gave you above. And voila, you'll start debugging exactly where you want, without evaluating all your initial code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the easiest/quickest solution is to move the specific line of code to the top of the file (i.e. line 1, not line 1,100), so that it runs first when debugging.